# A/B testing with multiple conversion goals

Tags: statistical-significance, multivariate-analysis, ab-test

Suppose I run A/B testing with two variants on my website and track multiple conversion goals (e.g. goal a: post a comment, goal b: click facebook like button). To make it simple for now, a conversion goal is a binominial variable that can take a value of either 0 or 1.

The system I use for capturing the results lets me only see the totals, e.g.:

```
_Variant A_  
Total samples: 10000  
Total conversions goal a: 400  
Total conversions goal b: 600  


_Variant B_  
Total samples: 10000  
Total conversions goal a: 750  
Total conversions goal b: 500
```

In the case of having only one conversion goal, I could use a z-test or chi-square to determine if both variants differ significantly. The number of samples and the number conversions is all the input I need.

In the case of having multiple conversion goals, what method can I use to determine if two variants are significantly different?